# C# How to add an item to List from another class

Tags: c#, list

So I'm trying to make a PhoneBook Console App. One option is to AddContact. Problem is, once I've added a new item to the list and I return to main menu, then use the ViewAllContacts option, this new item is not displayed. Just need some help figuring this one out. Here's my code:

```
 public class Contacts
    {
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public int ContactNumber { get; set; }

        public List<Contacts> listMethod()
        {
            List<Contacts> contacts = new List<Contacts>();
            {
                contacts.Add(new Contacts { ContactName = "John", ContactNumber = 1 });
                contacts.Add(new Contacts { ContactName = "Jack", ContactNumber = 2 });
                contacts.Add(new Contacts { ContactName = "Jay", ContactNumber = 3 });

            }
            return contacts;
        }
```

Then I've got another Class called AppOptions which has a few methods such as SearchContact, ViewContact, ViewAllContacts and AddContact. I'll just show AddContact:

```
 public void addContact()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("       Add Contact:");
            Console.WriteLine("       ------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Name");
            string newName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Number");
            int newNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var b = contactobj.listMethod();
            b.Add(new Contacts { ContactName = newName, ContactNumber = newNumber });
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Contact Saved");
            Menu menuObj = new Menu();
            menuObj.MenuMethod();
        }
```

Comment: `listMethod` always creates a new list containing three contacts. You need to persist that list in a property or field. Then you can use that property to add contacts or to search etc. them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are mixing some concepts. Your Contacts class contains the 'Entity' Contact and also contains the 'Repository' pattern to access to the contact entities.

When you invoke the listMethod method, you always return the list created in that method. A better approximation could be:

```
public class Contact
{
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public int ContactNumber { get; set; }
}

public class ContactManager
{
    private List<Contact> Contacts {get; set; = new List<Contact>();
    public List<Contacts> List() {
         return Contacts;
    }
    public void Add(Conctact contact) {
         Contacts.Add(contact);
    }
    public void Add(string name, int number) {
         Contacts.Add(new Contact(name, number));
    }
    //Other access methods to the internal list

}
```

Then the AppOptions class could be:

```
class AppOptions 
{
     private ContactManager {get; set; } = new ContactManager();     

     public void addContact()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("       Add Contact:");
                Console.WriteLine("       ------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Name");
                string newName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Number");
                int newNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                ContactManager.Add(newName, newNumber); 
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Contact Saved");
                Menu menuObj = new Menu();
                menuObj.MenuMethod();
            }
}
```

The idea is that the ContactManager provides you the access to the data. In this case, as data is not persisted in database, you need to maintain a reference to ContactManager in memory